# Losing Thread Context and Principal in Owin between WebApi and SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, signalr, owin

hows it going? I'm doing a SignalR project to where I'm having a rather difficult time in handling the concept of the OWIN Context being preserved between the WebAPI (REST) and SignalR.

The basic concept is that I use WebAPI to have a login page, where a user sends me in credentials to which I process, try to preserve some information after doing a DB search, set the Authorization and IPrincipal with a Claims and then pass the user back a generated Auth Token.

With SignalR I have the Javascript passing back in the Query String the authorization token. The idea was that it was suppose to match to see if the Owin context would match up with the token that you pass through when trying to do a SignalR connection. It would allow you to connect to a hub with the Authorization Attribute as suggested by the SignalR documentation.

## StartUp.CS

```
//SignalR
        app.Map("/listener", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);


            map.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Provider = new QsoAuthBearerProvider()
            });

            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration ();
            hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            hubConfiguration.Resolver = GlobalHost.DependencyResolver;


            GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout =  TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20); 
            GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
```

## QsoAuthBearerProvider.CS

```
public class QsoAuthBearerProvider: OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{
    public override Task RequestToken(OAuthRequestTokenContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("connect"))
        {
            var value = context.Request.Query.Get("authToken");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                context.Token = value;
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

## LoginController.CS

Here I try to set the IIdentity of the person and everything.

```
namespace WebSocketServer.Controller
{
[RoutePrefix("login")]
public class LoginController : ApiController
{

    private static readonly log4net.ILog Log = ...

    private string CreateSessionKey()
    {
        //Creates a token key and passes it back as a string
    }


    private ClaimsPrincipal SetOwinContext(string sessionKey, UserCreds creds)
    {
        var userRepo = (User repository);
        var trackingRepo = (Tracking Repository);
        try
        {
            bool authenticated = false;

            authenticated = //Check with 3rd party if creds are good

            if (authenticated)
            {
                using (IDbConnection con = new SqlConnection(Constants.CONN_STR))
                {
                    var builder = new SqlBuilder();

                    var query = //My query for checking things using Dapper

                    var user = con.Query<SystemUser>(query.RawSql, query.Parameters).First();

                    if (user == null || (user.LockedOut != false && user.LockedOut != null)) return null;

                    userRepo.SuccessfulLogin(creds.Username);
                    var owinContext = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();

                    var claims = new List<Claim>
                    {

                        //Name
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, sessionKey),

                        //Username
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, creds.Username??""),

                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Actor,user.LastName + ", " + user.FirstName),

                        //SystemId in Db
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid, user.SystemUserId.ToString() ??""),

                        //ConnectionId
                        //new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, " "),

                        //Authenticated
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Authentication, "true"),

                        //Token
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Thumbprint, sessionKey),

                        //Machine Ip
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.WindowsDeviceClaim, creds.MachineIp ?? ""),

                        //Default View
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.GroupSid, user.DefaultViewId?.ToString() ?? ""),

                        //Role
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, (user.IsAdmin != null && user.IsAdmin == true) ? "Admin" : "")
                    };

                    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

                    var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;
                    owinContext.Authentication.User = claimsPrincipal;

                    var tracking = new ConnectionTracking
                    {
                        Authenticated = true,
                        SystemUserId = user.SystemUserId,
                        Token = sessionKey,
                        MachineIp = creds.MachineIp
                    };

                    trackingRepo.Add(tracking);
                    trackingRepo.Save();

                    return claimsPrincipal;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            trackingRepo.Dispose();
            userRepo.Dispose();
        }
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    /// <summary>
    /// Login registration
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userCreds">String containing user name and password</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    //[ActionName("register")]
    public JObject Post([FromBody]UserCreds creds)
    {

        try
        {

            var privatePrincial = SetOwinContext(CreateSessionKey(), creds);
            var principal = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();

            if (principal.Authentication.User != null)
            {

                var claim = principal.Authentication.User.FindAll(o => o.Type == ClaimTypes.Thumbprint)
                    .First<Claim>();
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User;
                return JObject.FromObject(new
                {
                    token = claim.Value                        
                });
            }
            else
            {
                return JObject.FromObject(new { token = "-1" });
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex.ToString());
            return JObject.FromObject(new { error = ex.ToString() });

        }

    }

}
}
```

## HubAuthorizeAttribute.CS

```
namespace WebSocketServer.Authentication
{
/// <summary>
/// Custom hub authorization
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class HubAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog Log = ...

    private string _ConnId { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Invocation for hub; Gets the connection string id
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hubIncomingInvokerContext"><see cref="IHubIncomingInvokerContext"/></param>
    /// <param name="appliesToMethod"></param>
    /// <returns>Boolean</returns>
    public override bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubIncomingInvokerContext, bool appliesToMethod)
    {
        try
        {


            var principal = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();
            //hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context.QueryString.Get("authToken");
            if (principal != null && principal.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
            {
                this._ConnId = hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context.ConnectionId;


                return true;
            }

            return false;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected override bool UserAuthorized(IPrincipal user)
    {
        if (user == null) return false;

        var userPrincipal = user as IUserPrincipal;

        return userPrincipal != null && userPrincipal.Authenticated;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Authorization function for hub, works only if principal authenticated is true
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hubDescriptor"><see cref="HubDescriptor"/></param>
    /// <param name="request"></param>
    /// <returns>Boolean if person can access hub or not</returns>
    public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, IRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            var principal = HttpContext.Current.User as IUserPrincipal;

            return principal != null && principal.Authenticated == true;


            //return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

So what happens is in my hub Im using [HubAuthorize] attribute over it and try to access the current context. Now the Request context always has the User in there as null, same with Thread.CurrentPrincipal, HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext(). So it appears that after the send back with the WebAPI the context seems to be lost.

I dont know how in Owin, I can search through different instances of Identies or Principals, so I can look through the claims there.

I do know that my SignalR does work as is, without any attribute on top. My code doesnt seem to interfere when it negotiates and connects. I do see the query string with my authToken involves being passed through and I am able to see that in my QsoAuthBearerProvider.RequestToken() function. In the context I can see that its in there, but doesnt preserve any User information.

We have Angular as a pure frontend, and SignalR is on its own running site acting as a middleware.

So thanks for any help you can provide at this point. I've been banging my head over this for several days and have made little progress.

Thanks!